# Restrict characters in TextBox of UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp

My TextBox should only allow what you can type in a basic calculator like numbers `0 to 9` and `% * / - + . ( )` So, no letters and other characters. I tried the following from another SO thread but it's not doing anything. You can still type pretty much everything in the TextBox.

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if ((e.Key < VirtualKey.NumberPad0 || e.Key > VirtualKey.NumberPad9) & (e.Key < VirtualKey.Number0 || e.Key > VirtualKey.Number9))
   {
       e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using UWP TextBox.TextChanging to ignore wrong data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186357/using-uwp-textbox-textchanging-to-ignore-wrong-data)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following method to allow what you need input.

.xaml:

```
<TextBox Width="200" Height="100" TextChanging="TextBox_OnTextChanging" />
```

.cs

```
private void TextBox_OnTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        char[] chars = { '%', '*', '/', '-', '+', '.', '(', ')' };
        sender.Text = new String(sender.Text.Where(c => (char.IsDigit(c) || chars.Contains(c))).ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void textBox_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(sender.Text, @"^-?\d+\.?\d+[-+*\/]-?\d+\.?\d+$") && sender.Text != "")
    {
        int position = sender.SelectionStart - 1;
        sender.Text = sender.Text.Remove(position, 1);
        sender.SelectionStart = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but KeyPress events aren't available in UWP?

Comment: @AdamMcMahon You are correct. I have changed the code so it should work with UWP.

Comment: getting red underlines under \d \. \/ in the regex line

Comment: @EsAMe I have edited to fix the issue had to add a @ before the string.

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'StartIndex cannot be less than zero.'

Comment: Sound like sender.SelectionStart is initialized to 0 so your statement sender.Text = sender.Text.Remove(position, 1); becomes sender.Text = sender.Text.Remove(-1, 1);

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest method (IMO)**

If you target Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (introduced v10.0.16299.0) then you can use the TextBoxBeforeTextChanging event.
Below example restricts the user to numeric only, but can easily be expanded upon.

```
private void TextBox_OnBeforeTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    args.Cancel = args.NewText.Any(c => !char.IsDigit(c));        
}
```

Alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55948913/7446765) looks like it does pretty much what you want it to, without having to target the Fall Creators Update.

Comment: Could you please expand it then cause I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: TextBoxBeforeTextChanging  is not enough, use can bypass this using Input Method Editor, which ignores text events.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a regex extension property provided in UWP XAML toolkit. Simply choose validation type decimal or you can use your own regex.

```
<TextBox extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="^\s*\+?\s*([0-9][\s-]*){9,}$" />

<TextBox extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationMode="Forced”
       extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationType="Decimal" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxregex

Answer (score 0):

I like [Faywang's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11602935/faywang-msft) answer. Here's another approach.

```
    // Restrict TextBox punctuation, digits, use of CTRL key and emoji (set on textbox)
    // cancel must be true if either a, b or c are true, and d is true
    // cancel must be false if both a, b, or c are false, and d is true or false
    // (a || b || c) ^ d
    private void BlahTextBox_BeforeTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Cancel = args.NewText.Any(c => (char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsDigit(c) || char.IsControl(c)) ^ IsAllowedChar(c));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allow special punctuation only
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="c"></param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    private bool IsAllowedChar(char c)
    {
        // allow hyphen and single quote
        switch ((char)c)
        {
            case (char)39:
                return char.IsPunctuation(c) && !(c == (char)39);
            case (char)45:
                return char.IsPunctuation(c) && !(c == (char)45);
            default:
                return char.IsPunctuation(c);
        }
    }
```